# How to override the _createStripeToken function in odoo 12

Tags: javascript, odoo-12

I'm looking for a way to override the _createStripeToken function of the payment_stripe_sca module in odoo 12.

I am doing it like this but the console.log is not displayed. If I add this console log in the original one it is displayed

```
    PaymentForm.include({

    /**
     * @override
     * @private
     * @param {Event} ev
     * @param {DOMElement} checkedRadio
     * @param {Boolean} addPmEvent
     */
    _createStripeToken: function (ev, $checkedRadio, addPmEvent) {
        console.log("Adfadsfasdfasdfas")
    }

})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [patch](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#patching-an-existing-class) the payment form class and add the js file to the frontend assets (`web.assets_frontend`).

- Override the `_createStripeToken` function:

  ```js
  odoo.define('stack_overflow.payment_form', function (require) {
      "use strict";

      var PaymentForm = require('payment.payment_form');

      PaymentForm.include({
          _createStripeToken: function (ev, $checkedRadio, addPmEvent) {
              var self = this;
              console.log("Adfadsfasdfasdfas");
              return this._super.apply(this, arguments);
          },
      });
  });
  ```
- Add the file to the front end assets:

  ```xml
  <template id="assets_frontend" inherit_id="web.assets_frontend" name="Payment Stripe SCA Assets">
      <xpath expr="." position="inside">
          <script type="text/javascript" src="/stack_overflow/static/src/js/payment_form.js"></script>
      </xpath>
  </template>
  ```

Check [assets management](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/12.0/reference/javascript_reference.html#assets-management) for details.